# config dblib in debian 9 stretch

Tags: php, sql-server, debian-stretch

i want to connect to sqlserver

i have  this

```
php -v 
PHP 7.2.14-1+0~20190113100742.14+stretch~1.gbpd83c69 (cli) (built: Jan 13
2019 10:07:43) ( NTS )Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.2.14-1+0~20190113100742.14+stretch~1.gbpd83c69, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

[image]

where i used sqlser

```
$conn = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=xxxx', 'user', 'pass');
```

i have this problem

```
SQLSTATE[01000]: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.2.so.0.1' : file not found
```

but this file is exite in path

and when i used DBLIB

```
$conn = new PDO( "dblib:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname;", $username, $pw);
```

after many secand (2 minutes)  i have this problem

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (severity 9)
```

Comment: Some time the config for command line PHP and Apache PHP is different, check the config using `phpinfo()` method

Comment: PDO PDO support enabled
PDO drivers dblib, mysql, odbc, sqlsrv
pdo_dblib
PDO Driver for FreeTDS/Sybase DB-lib enabled
Flavour freetds
pdo_mysql

Comment: PDO Driver for MySQL enabled
Client API version mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
Directive Local Value Master Value
pdo_mysql.default_socket /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: PDO_ODBC
PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) enabled
ODBC Connection Pooling Enabled, strict matching
pdo_sqlsrv
pdo_sqlsrv support enabled
ExtensionVer 5.3.0

Comment: the same config in phpinfo()